# Design unreal engine vr shopping app without controllers

Tags: unreal-engine4

I want to design a VR shopping app using unreal engine. In this app, you're in a virtual mall and you can choose which store you want to go to. If you find something you like and checkout then the bill will be on your credit card and the items will actually be shipped to your address just like a normal shopping app.

1. Can this be done? If yes, is 6 months enough time for me to learn how to do this from scratch?
2. Is unreal engine the best choice to create this app with?
3. Can I create this app without needing controllers? My Samsung Gear VR doesn’t have any controllers and it only has a click as well as forward and backward buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I will make the answer clear as possible .

- Can this be done? , yes it can be done and quite straight forward to anyone who have enough experience with unreal engine.
- 6 Months? , it depends on how dedicated are you to learn the engine, but I would say its possible if you are talking care of learning unreal engine as its your full time job , bec I've build my main building for my university within only 8 days .
- Here is the link you can start [Unreal engine Acadamey](https://academy.unrealengine.com/), look for beginner courses before started something higher.
- Is unreal engine the best choice to create this app with?, unreal engine and unity both are awesome to deliver such product, but learning unity without programming skills could be quite annoying for beginner like you .
- Can I create this app without needing controllers? , You can develop the idea without controller, but since its VR based, you should develop it while using the full set bec VR is quite expensive and you need to optimize everything to run smoothly, so developing it without VR kit you will have much troubles when you convert your final product to VR support if your game is not optimized from beginning for VR.

Hope that clear some points for you, keep in mind there is no highway to learn something, if you love what you doing you will spend all your time enjoying learning it.

Best of luck